# Finding Missing Numbers series when Data Is Grouped in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write a query that will calculate the missing numbers with their count in a sequence when the data is "grouped". The data are in multiple groups & each group is in sequence.

For Ex. I have number series like 1001-1050, 1245-1270, 4571-4590 and all numbers like 1001,1002,1003,....1050 is stored in Table1 and from that Table1 some numbers are stored in another table Table2. E.g. 1001,1002,1003,1004,1005.

I want to get output like this:

```
Utilized Numbers | Balance Numbers  |
----------- -------------------------
1001 - 1005 = 5  | 1006 - 1050 = 45 |  
1245 - 1251 = 7  | 1252 - 1270 = 19 | 
4571 - 4573 = 3  | 4574 - 4590 = 17 |
```

The number of each series is single field which is stored in both tables.

Comment: GIve sample data for table1 and table2 in a proper table format which gives your expected output.

Comment: Table1 Data :  
    ------------  
    1001 
    1002
    1003
    1004
    1005
    1006
     . 
     .
     .
    to
    1050  
 
    Table2 Data :
     --------------------
    1001
    1002
    1003
    1004
    1005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really explained your data, but guessing that "Utilized" are the numbers found in both Table1 and Table2, and "Balance" are the numbers only in Table1.

You can get the result at least this way, it's a little bit messy, mostly because of formatting the results:

**Edit**: This is a new version that does not use lag.

```
select 
    min (case when C2 = 1 then MINID end), max (case when C2 = 1 then MAXID end), max(case when C2=1 then ROWS end),
    min (case when C2 = 0 then MINID end), max (case when C2 = 0 then MAXID end), max(case when C2=0 then ROWS end)
from (
    select min(ID) as MINID, max(ID) as MAXID, count(*) as ROWS, C2, row_number() over (partition by C2 order by min(ID)) as GRP3 from (
        select *, ID - RN as GRP1, ID - RN2 as GRP2 from (
          select 
              T1.ID, row_number() over (order by T1.ID) as RN, 
              case when T2.ID is NULL then 0 else 1 end as C2,
              row_number() over (partition by case when T2.ID is NULL then 0 else 1 end order by T1.ID) as RN2,
              T2.ID as ID2 
          from #Table1 T1 
          left outer join #Table2 T2 on T1.ID = T2.ID
        ) X
    ) Y
    group by GRP1, GRP2, C2
) Z
group by GRP3 
order by 1
```

The idea here is to have a row number ordered by Table1.ID, and it's compared to the Table1.ID, and if the difference changes, then it's a new group. The same logic is used second time, but now partitioned differently for rows that exist in Table2 to handle changes between "Utilized" and "Balance".

From those groupings you can get the min and max value + number of rows. There's one additional grouping with min/max and case to format the result into 2 columns.

See the [demo](http://rextester.com/FGQMT71704).

Comment: Thank you @James Z.. But LAG function is not working in SQL Server 2008. So you have any alternate option for that?

Comment: your query is not working in **SQL Server 2005 & 2008**. Please help me..I am in **Stuck**

Comment: I rewrote the grouping logic using second row_number, this should work the same way.

Comment: @ James Z : Waw.**you are Champion**.Thankss alottt...this is i want. 10 Out of 10.**Thank you dear**

Comment: how to select(want to display ) another field of Table1 or Table2 in select statement? Plz help me...plzzzzzzz

Comment: Run the inner parts of the SQL so you'll figure out how it works. The outer parts just do the formatting, so if you can do that somewhere else, it gets lot simpler -- or otherwise you'll have to add more logic there however you need the fields to be shown.

Comment: Can you rewrite the above query with select another fields of table? Please, its very urgent dear.Please help me...

Comment: Well, no. First, "another fields on table" tells me nothing what you want, and if you wanted something else, that should have been in your question.

Comment: Please James help me...how to select another field of table1 or table2 in first select statement in above query?

Comment: Just change `ID` to the other field? Still no idea what you're asking because you just keep repeating the same unclear thing.

Comment: I have one more field in table1 i.e. Ticket_type. Now I want to display or show Ticket_type column in result with same query. I tried more times but I am not able to select any fields of table in select statement. I understand you are used iner join of both tables in inner part of query. But I am unable to select another field of table1 or table2 using table alias.I got error in SQL Server like : multi-part identifier "T1.Ticket_type" could not be bound. So how we resolve this issue? I want to query like : select T1.Ticket_type, ....... the above query will continue. Please James help me.

Comment: Without proper examples it's totally impossible to know what you need. Write a new question -- and include good examples, preferably with create table & insert clauses.